# Browser don't change image automatically

Tags: android

I created two background images for portrait and landscape, I want browser change background image automatically when client rotate their screen. Unfortunately, it didn't work as I desire ...

```
<script>
    var stage = document.getElementById('stage');

    var width = screen.width;
    var height = screen.height;

    stage.style.width = width + 'px';
    stage.style.height = height + 'px';

    if (width < height) {
      // portrait
      stage.style.background = 'url(portrait.png) no-repeat';
    } else {
      // landscape
      stage.style.background = 'url(landscape.png) no-repeat';
    }

    var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

    window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {

        if (screen.width < screen.height) {
          // portrait
          stage.style.background = 'src(portrait.png) no-repeat';
          alert('Portrait');
        } else {
          // landscape
          stage.style.background = 'src(landscape.png) no-repeat';
          alert('Landscape');
        }

    }, false);

</script>
```

you can help me to improve it?

Comment: Error message in console? Also, why is this tagged with android? I get that you might be building a hybrid mobile app, but that hardly qualifies for usage of that tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS3 media queries for orientation-specific styles.

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```